# Memory allocation in various functions?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm creating two different functions, both of which need to use a pointer.

So I need to use malloc in the function which I enter the values of the pointer, then be able to sort the values of the allocated pointer in another function(That part sometimes work, but always causes the program to crash).

If I use malloc in my main function, I can easily use the pointer in both of my user-made functions, but like I mentioned, I'm trying to use malloc in the function that I made, and make it work in other functions.

So my question is, is this possible? Also I don't wanna malloc on a global scale(if that's even possible).

Comment: please post the code?

Comment: Return the pointer from the function which allocates the memory.

Comment: If I post the code, it's only going to be even more confusing. It's a bit large program and uses multiple files. In general, my two functions are enterdata(pointer), and sort_data(pointer). I need to use malloc in "enterdata", yet make sure the program doesn't crash when afterwards, I use sort_data.

Comment: `then be able to sort the values of the allocated pointer in another function(That part sometimes work, but always causes the program to crash).` ... Why sort allocated pointer values? That's asking for trouble.  and if you use malloc in a function, return the value from malloc to the function caller so that the 3rd party program can use and free the memory that your function allocated.

Comment: You don't allocate "the pointer", but an object and get a address of that object.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code, I can't help much, but in the function that has `malloc`, just make that function return the pointer. You could also have that function takes a pointer to a pointer and allocate it like that.

**Way 1**

```
void* f1()
{
    return malloc(szData);
}

void f2(void* ptr)
{
    // do stuff with pointer
}

int main()
{
    void* ptr = NULL;
    ptr = f1();
    f2(ptr);
    free(ptr);
}
```

---

**Way 2**

```
void f1(void** ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(szData);
}

void f2(void* ptr)
{
    // do stuff with pointer
}

int main()
{
    void* ptr = NULL;
    f1(&ptr);
    f2(ptr);
    free(ptr);
}
```

There are many different ways of doing this. I hope these two examples are enough for you to solve your problem.

Comment: You should free that memory.

Comment: @GregM: Letting the runtime release resources you reserve is bad coding style. If you allocate memory, you should `free` it. (the same for files, etc.) You don't check the results, and using a pointer argument to return a value, although the function is `void` is bad style, too. It is much more straigth forward to return the pointer. Finally, `main` has a discourage signature. Use prototype declarators.

Comment: @Olaf this is supposed to be a simple explanation. The user asked a question and I answered. If you're unhappy with my answer, make the edit because comments can change.

Comment: @GregM: It is your answer. Edits are to correct spelling or formating, but not fundamental "flaws". An answer which does someones homework by providing code (not just correcting it) should at least show good coding practice. Also comments are to add clarifications and enhancements to the reader, which I did.

Comment: @Olaf  Then post your own answer. There is nothing wrong with that. Arguing with me is going to get you nowhere.